# How to Get Multiple Instrument Candles in one GET request with Oanda's API

Tags: rest, curl, get

A request for a single instrument's candles is, e.g.

```
"https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/instruments/EUR_USD/candles?price=M&from=2020-06-01T10%3A00%3A00.000000000Z&granularity=M10"
```

to get all EUR_USD 10 minute midpoint candles from a specified time. How can I alter the above to get multiple instruments in one request? For example, an attempt to get EUR_USD *and* GBP_USD candles, such as

```
"https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/instruments/EUR_USD%2CGBP_USD/candles?price=M&from=2020-06-01T10%3A00%3A00.000000000Z&granularity=M10"
```

does not work.

I would like to get up to 50 different instruments in one request and avoid the need to loop on the client side and make 50 separate requests.